# Regular Expresion: Ignore escaped items (Javascript)

Tags: javascript, regex

I've spent an insane amount of time trying to find the appropriate `regEx` to select in a string, only those elements that are enclosed by unescaped 
custom delimiters (with delimiters included).

---

**My custom delimiters** :

> `${...}`

**Example of a string**:

> This`${ is }`a clear`${ and simple}` example `${string}`, where {`${only}`} only the \${highlighted} parts should be selected.

**Expected result**:

> [ "${ is }" , "${ and simple}" , "${string}" , "${only}" ]

---

I've been able to define the regular expression to select all the tokens in the string :

> `/(\${\s?\S+\s?})/g`

**However I still can't figure out how to ignore the wole ESCAPED item, as well as  the extra braket returned in `${result-4}`**

I've been performing my tests here:
https://regex101.com/r/XsQFqS/1

I would apprecciate any kind of help with this.

Comment: Are you trying to extract or replace or ...? Try [`\\(?:\${\s?\S+\s?})|(\${\s?\S+\s?})`](https://regex101.com/r/XsQFqS/2)

Comment: Within ES2018 compatible JS environment, you may use [`/(?<=(?<!\\)(?:\\{2})*)\${[^{}]*}/g`](https://regex101.com/r/3Y9jUq/3). But in other cases, you can rely on capturing, [`/((?:^|[^\\])(?:\\{2})*)(\${[^{}]*})/g`](https://regex101.com/r/3Y9jUq/2)

Comment: The only proposed expresion working is the ES2018 one, provided by @WiktorStribiżew , but it disallows curly brakets inside the delimiters. I've been able to simplify it to :```/(?<!\\)\${[^{}]*}/g``` , but still, is pretty limiting.

Comment: This "simplified" regex will match unexpected strings like ``\\${content}`` (here, a backslash preceded the delimiter that must be matched). Also, what do you mean by not supporting braces inside? How do you plan to detect the delimiter right-hand boundary if there can be braces? Also, you do not really need the lookbehind. **What is your end goal**? What is the **expected result** for the sample string above?

Comment: I guess you are right. It has total sense. Thanks for your time. If you post it as a formal anwser i close the question with it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In practical terms, it seems to be impossible to match only the required elements using a basic JavaScript regex. However, it can be done with the old [**SKIP what's to avoid*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24535912/8291949) trick using capture groups, i.e. `What_I_want_to_avoid|(What_I_want_to_match)`, like this:

```
#What_I_want_to_avoid: escaped elemets (odd no. of escape characters)
(?:[^\\]\\(?:\\\\)+|[^\\]\\)\${[^{}]*}
|
#What_I_want_to_match: unescaped element (or even no. of escape characters)
[^\\](?:\\\\)*(\${[^{}]*})
```

Again, the key idea here is to completely disregard the overall matches returned by the regex engine: `$0` is the trash bin. Instead, we only need to check capture group `$1`, which, when set, contains what we are looking for.

[**Test Demo**](https://regex101.com/r/HvYaqq/1)

```js
const regex = /(?:[^\\]\\(?:\\\\)+|[^\\]\\)\${[^{}]*}|[^\\](?:\\\\)*(\${[^{}]*})/g;
const str = `This\${ is }a clear\${ and simple} example \${string}, where {\${only}} only the \\\${highlighted} parts should be selected  \\\\\${allowing} escaping and unescaping: \\\\\\\${not}, \\\\\\\\\${yes}`;
let m;

while ((m = regex.exec(str)) !== null) {
    // This is necessary to avoid infinite loops with zero-width matches
    if (m.index === regex.lastIndex) {
        regex.lastIndex++;
    }
    
    m.forEach((match, groupIndex) => {
      if(groupIndex && match)
        console.log(`Found match, group ${groupIndex}: ${match}`);
    });
}
```

Comment: The idea is to skip the scaped items, and your code is returning them.

Comment: @colxi actually, you write "trying to find" and "Expected extractions" in the OP. Sounds a whole lot like matching, or what do I miss?

Comment: I'm sorry if my description is not clear enougth. I've edited. What i'm trying to get is only the elements that are not escaped.

Comment: @colxi Isn't this exactly what my pattern does? Have you tried the Test/Demo? Are the green $1 values not what you want?

Comment: I think i need some coffee. my apologies.